# LWUIT createTrueTypeFace Font

Tags: java-me, fonts, lwuit

I need to use a custom `Font` for my J2ME Application, the `Font` name is verdana, I'm using LWUIT, I have downloaded the .ttf file for my `Font` and add it to my package and tried to load it using

Font.createTrueTypeFace method but I got --> unsupported operation exception

so can any one please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TrueType fonts only work in platforms where the isTrueType supported returns true. Currently in LWUIT it doesn't work anywhere since we never completed that feature before leaving Oracle.